# Can I expose my VM to public without reserving external IP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I want to make my google cloud VM open to public without reserving external IP just like the App Engine does.
Some random name-number address would be perfect.

I've checked google docs and all it suggests is to use external IP for VM.

no code

I expect to use some other google service (without configuring any backend or frontend as it is covered by VM) or VM configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a VM, by default, you have an ephemeral external IP, free and not reserved. However, when your VM restart, the IP will change. The VM can restart by manual operation, but also automatically. Thereby, if an eternal service know an IP, it has to be updated with the new one. And as you can't manage when the VM restart, it's not reliable for production environment.

You also talked about name, I guess you mean DNS. It exists internally (internal DNS in your VPC for reaching your VM by their internal name) but no externally. You have to configure your own DNS with the IP. But, as mention before, the IP can change at any moment...

However, solutions exist.

The easiest and cheapest: reserve an IP address. It's free when attached to a VM running. If your VM is stopped, you have to pay the reserved IP.

You can also define a load balancer in front of your VM, which become your back end. The loadbalancer cost a little but can route directly the flow to your VM, even without VM with external IP. Only the IP of the loadbalancer is exposed (and you have all the protection of ddos attack, firewalls,...)